# “An error occurred while trying to run the script.” in the UI Automation instrument?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

When I try to run a `UI Automation` script on `iOS 6` with `iphone simulator 6.0` I am getting the following error:

`"An error occurred while trying to run the script."`

Please Help!
While working fine with `iphone simulator 5.1` with `ios5`.

Comment: I trust you did retry and restart. Instruments is not the most reliable software and sometimes it needs to be closed or computer restarted.

Comment: Are you getting that error when running the Instruments GUI? Or from the command line?

Comment: I am getting error when running the instruments GUI

Comment: @Abhishek did you resolve this? I'm facing the same issue and I'm curious if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Xcode. Some suggest the following (didn't work for me, no old iOS folder).
Assuming you have the latest iOS, now this would be iOS7, with latest version 7.0.3.

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/
mv 7.0 old7.0
ln -s 7.0.3 7.0
```

Some people claim this bug is fixed in different versions of Xcode (looks like it is back in Xcode 5.0.2 with Instruments 5.0.1), so you could try the latest Xcode beta or any version that you think worked on your computer (like Xcode 5.0.1 apparently)

What worked for me, however was to **plug in a device** and run my project **on the iPod/iPhone** instead of the simulator and it worked perfectly.